# Getting 'We're sorry, something went wrong' error with Devise and Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to setup an admin page using `Devise` and `Rails_Admin` gems. I have installed `devise` and created a `rails g devise USER`. I've create a `current_user` check in application layouts and set up routes according to instructions from Devise and a tutorial I'm following here: https://blog.codeplace.com/building-an-admin-panel-for-your-rails-app-d672159eb26e

Know that I had a DIY sessions/auth going before but have gotten rid of that pipeline. I'm also using 2 databases: one local postgresql and one remote AWS RDS.

When I try to hit `home#index`, I get the following error in the browser:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

In terminal the error is:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2019-11-06 12:47:03 -0500
   (28.6ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 2.0ms | Allocations: 626)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 141.2ms | Allocations: 177808)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 633ms (ActiveRecord: 31.4ms | Allocations: 257294)
```

Not sure if something is wrong in views or controller but I've scoured everything and can't find a solution. Here are my Rails MVC, database.yml and routes:

Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  establish_connection(:local)
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

controllers/home_controller.rb:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    byebug 
    if current_user
      redirect_to search_path
    end
  end
end
```

views/application_layout.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tml App</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> -->

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  <!-- <%= image_tag 'logo.png', :style => 'width:50%; height:50%;' %> -->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
      <div class="col-5">
        <%= image_tag 'logo-2.png', id: 'logo' %>
      </div>


      <div class="col-4 justify-content-center">
        <% if flash %>
          <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
          <div class="<%= flash_class(key) %>" id="error">
            <%= value %>
          </div>
            <% end %>
        <% else %> 
          <% flash.discard %>
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3">
        <% if current_user %>
        <%= link_to “Logout”, destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
        <% else %>
        <%= link_to “Login”, new_user_session_path %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= yield %>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  root 'home#index'

  get 'searches/index' => "searches#index"
  get 'searches/show' => "searches#show"
  get 'searches/search' => "searches#search", as: 'search' 


  get 'audits/show' => 'audits#show'     
  get 'audits/download' => 'downloads#show' 
  post 'audits/' => 'audits#create'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

and my database.yml file just in case it might be causing problems?

```
default: &default 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: tml_portal 
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>



development:
  aws:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: requests
    username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_username] %>
    password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_password] %>
    host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_host] %>
    cast: false 
    port: 3306
  local:
    <<: *default



production:
  aws:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: requests
    username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_username] %>
    password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_password] %>
    host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_host] %>
    cast: false 
    port: 3306
  local:
    <<: *default




test: 
  aws:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: requests
    username: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_username] %>
    password: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_password] %>
    host: <%= Rails.application.credentials[:aws_host] %>
    cast: false 
    port: 3306
  local:
    <<: *default
```

Comment: You are checking for `current_user` in `application/layout.html.erb` while you should be checking whether `user_signed_in`. That's the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your `application/layout.html.erb` you are checking for `current_user` which isn't set until a user is signed in. To identify whether a user has signed in, you should use the `user_signed_in` method that comes with `devise`. So your code becomes,

```
<div class="col-3">
   <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to “Logout”, destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
   <% else %>
        <%= link_to “Login”, new_user_session_path %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense but still having no luck even after changing the method to `user_signed_in`